# Python Django exception middleware for exception not in a view

Tags: python, django, exception

Whenever an exception is caught in my django app, I'd like to use a custom middleware class to process the exception and send an email.

```
import logging
from django.core.mail import send_mail


class ErrorMiddleware(object):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        self.logger.debug("Middleware has caught an exception. exception={}".format(exception.message))

        # send_mail("Your Subject", "This is a simple text email body.",
        #           "Yamil Asusta <hello@yamilasusta.com>", ["yamil@sendgrid.com"])

    return None
```

I've added the middleware to my settings file,

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    # custom middleware
    'buildconfig.middleware.ErrorMiddleware.ErrorMiddleware',
)
```

And written the following test case to test the that the middleware processes my exception...

```
from django.test import TestCase
from mock import patch
from mock import Mock

class TestErrorMiddleware(TestCase):

    def test_process_exception_catches_exceptions(self):
        raise Exception
```

However, when I run my test through manage.py, I don't see my log message showing up in my log.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you set up logging handlers correctly?

Comment: But... your test just raises an exception on its own. You're not running it in the context of a request, so how could the middleware possibly catch it?

Comment: I want it to catch all Exceptions, not just ones that occur from a request in a view.

Comment: But middleware is not magic. It can only catch errors that happen within the context that the middleware is actually run; that is, within a request.

Answer (score 3):

Every Middleware is initialised once the web server starts. but for that to happen you need an **__init__**() in the middleware.

```
def __init__(self, get_response):
  self.get_response = get_response
```

After the Middleware gets initialised, it needs to have a **__call__**() method which gets called on every request from the client. It is this method that is responsible for passing the controller over to the underlying middleware or calling the actual view after the last layer i.e. the view middleware.

```
def __call__(self, request):
    # Code to be executed for each request before
    # the view (and later middleware) are called.

    response = self.get_response(request)

    # Code to be executed for each request/response after
    # the view is called.

    return response
```

You need to return an **HTTPResponse()** from the process_exception() that will be to the middleware's **__call__()** in the **response** variable in the above code before passing it to the middleware above it on the way out.

Since you don't have the **__init__()** and the **__call__()** in your middleware class, your middleware is not getting initialised and thus handling each request as its passing to and fro the middleware layer.

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#init-get-response

Answer (score 1):

While the response from @cdx530 is correct, there is a backwards compatibility shim for middleware designed for Django pre-1.10 as MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES that provides (almost) the same functionality in the contemporary MIDDLEWARE approach, and imho presents a better structure and separation between the different middleware processing phases.

Simply derive your middleware class from MiddlewareMixin:

```
from django.middleware.common import MiddlewareMixin

class ErrorMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    ....
```

and unless you have overridden __init__ there is nothing else you need do.  __call__ will never be used in this case, which is fine for the old behaviour, and the mixin class will automatically call the get_request between your process_request and process_response/processs_exception.

Current Django docs includes a discussion of this topic here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware

including an explaining the subtle differences in behaviour.